# How to calculate the amplitude of two degenerate vacuums?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, symmetry-breaking

I've seen in textbooks and heard from lecturers that spontaneous symmetry breaking (SSB) does not happen in quantum mechanics because of the tunnelling between two degenerate vacua (i.e amplitude of two vacua a non-zero).

I conceptually understand this but I want to calculate this explicitly. So I start with a Hamiltonian
$$H=p^2 + (1-x^2)^2.$$
Expanding around two vacua $x_0 = \pm 1$, one finds two harmonic oscillators with perturbation in a higher order of $x$.
$$H_\pm = p^2 + 8x^2 \pm 24 x^3 + O(x^4).$$
If I call $|\Omega_\pm\rangle$ ground states of $H_\pm$, then I want to calculate the amplitude $\langle\Omega_+|\Omega_-\rangle$. **What is a good approximation method I can use to calculate this amplitude?** I don't really need to know the exact answer, just need to know if it is non-zero or not.

Comment: My 2 cents is that you will probably make faster progress reading about the double well potential or a sinusoidal potential than trying to build your own toy model, since the analysis is pretty non-trivial. Here is one paper that works out tunneling behavior for a double well potential: https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2521. If you do pursue your model, note that as written your potential only has one minimum, at $x=0$. I think what you want is something like $V(x) = (x+1)^2 (x-1)^2=(x^2-1)^2$.

Comment: Here's a PSE question about sinusoidal potentials: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/472117/spectrum-of-sinusoidal-potential

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for the comment. Sorry, it was a typo in the potential. it's not $V=(1+x^2)^2$ but rather $V=(1-x^2)^2$. Looking at the paper you suggested, it does have the potential I want in equation (3) so I think this answers the question.